# Simple MVC ASP.Net Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have the following sample controller code from a well recognized source:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{       
    MyStoreEntities storeDB = new MyStoreEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {     
        var albums = GetTopSellingAlbums(5);     
        return View(albums);
    }

    private List<Album> GetTopSellingAlbums(int count)
    {            
        return storeDB.Albums
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.OrderDetails.Count())
            .Take(count)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

I want to write a very simple test to check that 5 albums are returned from the Index() method.

I thought something like something like this might do it:

```
HomeController controller = new HomeController();
var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
var albums = (List<Album>)result.ViewData;
Assert.AreEqual(5, albums.Count);
```

But the value of the model.Count() is always 0.

Firstly, Am I missing something - is it possible?

Secondly, I am doing this to learn a lot of principles around legacy code.  I have this code, which I know can be seriously improved upon.  It also has no tests.

My plan is to cover the existing code with tests and the seriously redactor it.

So, please no responses such as 'bad practice' here or there or implement this layer or that patterns etc as that will come later.

Just the simplest way to test the above code would really help please :)

Perhaps even good blogs or books would also be helpful.

Thanks

Davy

Comment: do you have album data in database? does the website where the controller belongs to show data when connected to the same db as your test? do test and website use the same db-connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in learning about working with legacy code there is no better source than "Working With Legacy" Code book

Comment: Yeah,  I have Micheal Feathers book on the list to read - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the model with the `Model` property of the `ViewDataDictionary` class:

```
albums = (List<Album>)result.ViewData.Model;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Jan - However, the count of albums is always 0 and never 5 :(

Comment: And when you debug GetTopSellingAlbums returns 5 albums?